# symplectic surfaces in 4-manifolds

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Is it true that for any surface in a symplectic 4-manifold $X$, representing a given homology class of $H_2(X)$, we can assume it is symplectic? I mean for each second homology class, can we find a symplectic surface representing it?

Comment: If a surface is representing a homology class, then it must already be equipped with an orientation. And for surfaces orientations can be lifted to volume forms, which are the same thing as symplectic forms.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The $\omega$-area of the surface gives an obstruction. For example, if I take $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$, the anti-diagonal (graph of the antipodal map) is Lagrangian. The $\omega$ area of this is therefore $0$. Any other surface that is homologous to this will also have total area $0$ and thus there can't be a symplectic surface representing this class.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would guess that if the $\omega$ area of the homology class is positive, you can probably find a symplectic representative, but I haven't thought enough about this. Let me know if this modification of your question is of interest.

Comment: If you have an embedded symplectic surface representing some homology class with trivial normal bundle, then by a Moser-type argument you have a tubular neighborhood symplectomorphic to the product. Then by essentially a singular value decomposition argument, there is an almost complex structure on your manifold which restricts to this tubular neighborhood as the standard one which is $\omega$-compatible. So for at least surfaces with trivial normal bundle, one can turn the question into a pseudo-holomorphic existence question.